# Java: Create a command from String array

Tags: java, shell, cmd, escaping, exec

I have a String array containing a separated command - each parameter in a different cell.

I would like to have a method that gets a string array and that uses it to prepare a semantically-legal full command (i.e. that takes care of special chars, such as `<space>`, braces, etc.). Then, it should return the full command as one string

This is a very simple example for the usage I would like to have (If I had the `createCommand()` method):

```
String[] cmdParts = {"ls", "-l", "/tmp /home"};
String cmd = createCommand(cmdParts);
```

In the above example, I would expect `cmd` to contain the string `ls -l "/tmp /home"`

Is there a method that does this work, or something similar?

Comment: To find out if it's legal, you need to execute it.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but, it looks like you're asking to concatenate strings.

Comment: I wrote here a very simple scenario. The function should be more clever than just a string concatenator. For exmple, if one of the parameters contains `<space>` or `braces` or who knows what else, the function may need to add escape characters, more braces, etc.

Comment: Sorry to be blunt user3322273 but we won't code it for you. For example, escaping quotes in strings. You can search and find the answer. Please try that, and using the suggestions provided, and then post back with what issues you may be having, if any.

Comment: I don't expect anyone to code for me. I want to use a standard solution. so my actual question is whether you know a library that contains a similar method (like apache's stuff)

Answer (score 2):

You can just loop through the array and do it yourself easily. I can't think of anything immediately

```
String createCommand(String[] cmdParts) {

  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder()
  for(String cmdPart : cmdParts) {
    if (sb.length() > 0) {
      sb.append(" ");
    }
    sb.append(cmdPart);
  }
  return sb.toString();
}
```

Although it won't leave you with trailing or leading spaces.

Also note:

```
{"ls", "-l", "/tmp /home"}
```

Will not result in

```
ls -l "/tmp /home"
```

You need to add the quotes escaped to the last String.

```
{"ls", "-l", "\"/tmp /home\""}
```

Comment: I am looking for a method that will add automatically these escaped quotes

Comment: How would you know that "ls" and "-l" do not need the quotes, but "/tmp /home" does?

Comment: I would know it as I pass it to the function as one string which contains `<space>`. For making Unix treat multiple strings separated by space as one param, you should insert them to quotes

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate strings if that is what you mean. And put this in a method createCommand that gets a string array as input and outputs a concatenated string:

```
public String createCommand(String[] parts)
{
   String result = "";
   for(String part : parts)
   {
      result = result + part + " "; \\concatenates the result string with the next string in your parts array.
   }

   return result; 
}
```

Comment: Thank you but this is not what I need. See my response in the main thread. It should take care of special chars, such as `<space>`, braces, etc.

Answer (score 0):

It will be best if you use StringBuilder for various reasons. The compiler probably will convert your method to a StringBuilder anyway, but you don't want to rely on that. Item 51 of Effective Java is a good reference for why you should use StringBuilder in a situation like this.

As for the actual method, you will do something like this, but like you said, you're going to have to introduce logic inside the for loop to handle escaping particular characters and so on and so forth.

```
public String createCommand(String[] cmdParts) {
    StringBuilder newCommand = new StringBuilder();
    for(String s : cmdParts) {
        newCommand.append(s).append(" ");
    }
    return newCommand.toString();
}
```

Comment: P.S. Look into the String.format() method as it may give you some assistance with adding logic in the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

If you have java8, you can use following code:

`public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] cmdParts = {"ls", "-l", "/tmp /home"};
        String cmd = String.join(" ", cmdParts);
        System.out.println(cmd);
    }`

It is easier.If you don't have java8, you can use the others' code.

Comment: Does it take care of special chars? If yes, it sounds like a good solution. If I use Java 7, maybe there's some apache or some other lib that does the same?

Comment: Java8 is ok, you don't need to care about the special chars.